# Got error Unexpected response code 404 for my url while volley post request my code is

Tags: android

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url , new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("response", response.toString());
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("error", String.valueOf(error));
    }
})
{
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("name", paramName);
        params.put("email", paramEmail);
        return params;
    }
};

RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

}

> This is my code and i dont anderstand why this happned**Got error Unexpected response code 404 for my url while volley post request my code is**

and below is my back end code

```
public function postRequest(Request $request) {
    $response = array();
    $name = $request->input('name');
    $email = $request->input('email');

    $saveData = new Users();
    $saveData->name = $name;
    $saveData->email = $email;

    $saveData->save();

    if(isset($saveData)) {
        $response['code'] = 200;
        $response['status'] = 'success';
        $response['content'] = "Data saved Successfully";
    } else {
        $response['code'] = 400;
        $response['status'] = 'error';
        $response['content'] = "Error in data saving";
    }

    return response($response, $response['code'])
                ->header('content_type', 'application/json');
```

Got error Unexpected response code 404 for my url while volley post request my code is
    }**strong text**

Comment: your code is correct it is a server side problem because 404 it comes when resource isnot found on server

Comment: i checked my api in postman its work fine with same parameter that i passed in string request

Comment: asked to the backend person

Answer (score 1):

try this by adding the end of your code.

```
   int socketTimeout = 500000;//30 seconds - change to what you want
        RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        // Creating RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        // Adding the StringRequest object into requestQueue.
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```